# Userfrom X button stops code

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need some help ending some code, I have a button on my sheet (NewMonth) that calls UserFrom3 and then runs more code after the userform has been filled in and data copied to the sheet.

UserForm3 is a Date Selection. Once this has been filled in it that fills in cells on the sheet with the date, then runs the rest of the code from the NewMonth button.

The problem i am having is that if someone click the X button on the user from it still runs the code from the NewMonth button.

How can i get this to stop running??

Below is the code from both the NewMonth button and the userform.

UserForm:

```
Private Sub btnDateAdd_Click()
Dim rDate As Range, rDate2 As Range
Dim Month As String, Year As String

Month = ComboBox1.Value
Year = TextBox1.Value

Set rDate = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("C13")
Set rDate2 = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L13")

If ComboBox1.Value & TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select the Payment Month & Year required!"
Exit Sub
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select the Payment Month required!"
Exit Sub
ElseIf TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select the Payment Year required!"
Exit Sub
Else
rDate.Value = Format((28 & " " & Month & " " & Year), "dd mmm yy")
rDate2.Value = Format((28 & " " & Month & " " & Year), "mmmm yyyy")
End If

Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim iCtr As Long
For iCtr = 1 To 12
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Format(DateSerial(2007, iCtr, 28), "mmmm")
Next iCtr
End Sub
```

NewMonth Button:

```
Private Sub btnNewMonth_Click()
Dim front As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String, myRange As Range, myDate As Range
Dim rDate As Range, rDate2 As Range, myLabour As Range
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

Set myRange = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L9")                    'Payment No
Set myDate = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L13")                     'Date "MMMM YYYY"
Set rDate = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("C13")
Set rDate2 = Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L13")
MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Rows(2 & ":" & Sheets("Details").Rows.Count).ClearContents 'This clears all data below the header in Details
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Global").Rows(3 & ":" & Sheets("Global").Rows.Count).ClearContents   'This clears all data below in Global

UserForm3.Show
UserForm3.Hide

With ActiveSheet
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("N47").Copy                                              'Copies total to date Value
            .Range("N49").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                             'Pastes total to date Value to Total Last Payment
        End With
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("G43").Copy                                     'Copies This Months Labour
                .Range("G44").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                         'Pastes This Months Laboue into Last Payment
            End With
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("G56").Copy                                          'Copies Total VAT to Date
                .Range("G57").PasteSpecial xlValues                         'Pastes Total VAT to Date into Last Payment
            End With
                With ActiveSheet
                    .Range("N18:N34").Copy                                      'Copies CC Code Gross Value
                    .Range("J18:J34").PasteSpecial xlValues                     'Pastes CC Code Gross Value into Previous
                End With
    With ActiveSheet
        myRange.Value = myRange.Value + 1                               'Increases Payment No# by 1
        Range("A7").Activate                                                    'Selects Cell A7
    End With
End With
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\" & "Payment" & " " & myRange.Value & " " & myDate.Text & ".xlsm" 'This saves a new document in our naming convention

End Sub
```

Comment: This is pointless: `If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Unload Me` since that is what would happen anyway without any code. Your form should never unload itself - the calling code should do that. All your unload codes should simply hide the form and set a variable to indicate whether the form was cancelled or the Add button was clicked. The calling code should then test that variable and do whatever is required.

Answer (score 0):

I search through several site and tried multiple soultions and i managed to get it to work with the code below.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just be aware that using `End` is like shutting your computer down by pulling the plug out. All variables will lose their values.

Comment: Rory, do you know of a better way to code it? Thanks